# Construction of a scoring function to prioritize workers for a job depending on two properties

Tags: analysis, optimization, mathematical-modeling, scoring-algorithm

I have been trying to define a score function in order to prioritize a worker or another for a job depending on two properties of that worker.

If the worker has a negative result in the function, they won't be called. Then, if it is positive, they will be called in descending order.

Our variables and constants are:

- $n$ variable is the number of trainings the worker has attended
- $k$ constant is the minimum number of trainings a worker has to attend in order to be start being ellegible for a job.
- $N$ constant is the total number of trainings.
- $b$ variable is the percentage of jobs the workers have taken before in our company. We want our function to give a higher score to workers with less jobs taken before, in order to always tend to equitably distribute jobs between them.

Mathematically, I have written my problem as the following:

Given $k, N \in \Bbb N$ with $k\leq N$, we want to define a score function
$$
\begin{align*}
s: [0, N] \times [0,1] & \longrightarrow [-1,1]\\
(n,b) & \longmapsto s(n,b)
\end{align*}
$$
We want $s$ to have the following properties:

- $b$ always has to penalize the function. Therefore, given $n \in [0, N]$ and $b_1, b_2 \in [0,1]$ $\;\;\;b_1 > b_2 \implies s(n, b_1) < s(n, b_2) $
- Given any $b \in [0,1]$:

  - $n=0 \implies (\frac{n}{N} = 0  \; \land \; s(n, b) = -1)$
  - $n \in ]0, k[ \implies (\frac{n}{N} \in ]0, \frac{k}{N}[ \; \land \; s(n, b) \in ]-1, 0[)$
  - $n \in [k, N] \implies (\frac{n}{N} \in [\frac{k}{N}, 1]  \; \land \; s(n, b) \in [0, 1])$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Use `$\Bbb N$` for $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Shaun context of our problem added :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solver like Gurobi and use MIP.
Your function can be the objective $s(n,b) = s-b-z_1$
subject to below constraints
$b+z_1 \le 1 $
$ 1 \le z_1 + n$
$ N(z_2 - 1) \le k-n \le Nz_2$
$ -z_2 \le s \le 1-z_2$
$ 0 \le b \le 1$
$-Nn \le s \le Nn$
$0 \le n \le N $
where $z_1,z_2 $ are binary variables
$s,b,n $ are also variables with $s \in R, b,n \in Z$

Comment: Hi! That's a good idea but what I'm looking for (if that's possible) is a function I can, for instance, implement in python or excel in order to prioritize one worker or another from my list.

Comment: @DaniReinon in that case the constraints above are nothing but if-then-else statements e.g. if $n \le k$, then $-1 \le s \le 0$

Comment: I should be missing somwething about how to implement the above constraints as if-else statements in python. Could you develop a bit more, please? Much appreciated!

Comment: @DaniReinon you use something like if n <= k: s = numpy.random.rand()-1

Comment: thanks! I think I didn't explain myself well. There is no random component in our function. We want a smooth function whose range goes from -1 to 1 depending on the conditions above. That means that, given a fixed n, our function increases when b decreases. And given a fixed b, our function increases when n increases, following the rules above. Hope I could clarify a bit :)